# what strategy does sharepoint use for document history?

Tags: sharepoint

Is there better use of available storage space and faster network access using the same document with different versions vs saving different documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise the versioning will bring some performance advantages. This is since there will be less data for any search engine to index. Other than that I can't see any difference regarding performance.

The storage space should't be affected in a notable way.

My advice, use versioning with minors.